# react-native fetch async/await response filtering

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, async-await, fetch-api

I have response from my server like `buildings : [record1, record2, ...]` and I want to get only the array from that response. How can I get just the array from the Promise? I have tried some async/await things but I didn't understand how to use it in this code:

```
setupImpagination() {
    ....
    fetch(pageOffset, pageSize, stats) {
        return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/building/all?skip=${pageOffset}&limit=${pageSize}`)
            .then(response => {
            console.log('response.json() => ',response.json());
            response.json()
            })
            .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
            });

    }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

.then way

```
 fetch(pageOffset, pageSize, stats) {
        return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/building/all?skip=${pageOffset}&limit=${pageSize}`)
            .then(response => {
               console.log('response.json() => ',response.json());
               response.json()
            }).then(responseJson => {
               return responseJson.buildings
            }).catch((error) => {
               console.error(error);
            });

        }
    });
```

async/await way:

```
 async fetch(pageOffset, pageSize, stats) {
       try {
           const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/building/all?skip=${pageOffset}&limit=${pageSize}`);
           const responseJson = await response.json();
           return responseJson.buildings;
       } catch(error){
            console.error(error);
       }
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the reply the async/await solution has worked out for me. I had to add `async` before `fetch` then it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
async function fetchData (url, { type = 'json' } = {}) {
  return await (await fetch(url))[type]();
}
// Example: 
(async () => {
  console.log(await fetchData('http://canskit.com', { type: 'text' }));
})();
```

As the original js on ES7, not aim at react-native